# Search a text from TD and then take the value from the next TD

Tags: javascript

i'm new here so i hope i'm doing this right , i have a problem with a code i did , what i want to do is for example:

```
<td> FIND  THIS  </td>
<td> VALUE </td>
```

i want to have a function to search for "find this" and when found for exemple a var X to get "value"

I tried the following and when the element tag is (a) or (Li) It works , but when i do (tr) it doesn't , someone can help me please? i'm missing something i guess ...

```js
tds=document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0;i<tds.length;i++) {
  if(tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf('ND')>=0 ) {
  ND=tds[i+1].innerHTML;
    alert("ND4")
    alert(ND)             
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>ND</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
 <a>Coffee</a>
  <a>ND</a>
  <a>Milk</a>

<td>a</td>
<td>ND</td>
<td>c</td>
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` unless the content contains HTML. Use `.textContent` when there is no HTML as it is faster. Also, use `.nextElementSibling` to get the next `td` that comes after the one you already have. This is simpler than concatenating `id` values. There is also no need for the `break` at the end of your `true` branch because it was going to be done with that branch anyway. `break` is for exiting a loop early or for the end of `case` branches, not for `if` statements. If you need to leave any other kind of block early, use `return`.

Answer (score 1):

- Your HTML has problems, specifically the section of `TDs`.
- Those `TDs` must be inside a `TR` element.

---

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>ND</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  if (tds[i].innerHTML.indexOf('ND') >= 0) {
    ND = tds[i + 1].innerHTML;
    alert("ND4");
    alert(ND);
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>ND</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<a>Coffee</a>
<a>ND</a>
<a>Milk</a>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>ND</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```